# trouble with the include of a function in a subfile of index.php

Tags: php, arrays, function, null, include

In order to separate the php treatment from the HTML code I decided to put all my treatment php in a main file . php I called it library.php in this file I display all my functions.

The trouble I met is that this file is included in the main page index.php

The page index.php does include many other files.

When I call a file on GEt it is like that index.php?page=name_of_page

The trouble is that When I call this function in a subfile that is included on index.php

```
function affichMenuStat($paramStats){
    foreach ($paramStats as $stat){
        echo '<img src="'.$stat['image'].'"> <a href="'.$stat['lien'].'"> '.$stat['libelle'].'</a> | ';
    }
}
```

It says that the array is NULL, but when I display the array using var_dump on the main page index.php in the last line,

it says, that it exist.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Look at the code where you make the `affichMenuStat()` call and trace back to see if the param is set properly.

Comment: Dear Sir, I call the function like that <?php affichMenuStat($paramStats); ?>

Comment: here is the array $paramStats = array(
    'accueil' => array(
        'libelle' => 'ACCUEIL',
        'acces' => $data['accueil'],
        'lien' => 'accueil',
        'image' => 'images/home.png'
    ),
    'classement' => array(
        'libelle' => 'CLASSEMENT',
        'acces' => $data['classement'],
        'lien' => 'classement',
        'image' => 'images/award_star_bronze_3.png'
    ),

Comment: The problem is not in the function. Please add the peace of code of index.php that is calling this function.

Comment: I added it on the second comment

Comment: You have added the array's content. I've asked for the code of `index.php`

Comment: Most likely you have defined the array but then tried to access it out of scope, or overwritten it with null.

Comment: ok so you want to see how I include pages, so here is the code function getPage($var, $paramListepages) {

    if (array_key_exists($var, $paramListepages)) {
        // page trouvÃ©e => on l'inclut!
        include ($paramListepages[$var]['page']);
    } elseif (array_key_exists($var, $paramListepages) == false) {
        // page espectant la structure, non trouvÃ©e dans l'array => on l'inclut directement
        include('php/' . $var . '.php');
    } else {
        //Aucune page spÃ©cifiÃ©e => default page
        inlude('php/accueil.php');
    }
}

Comment: that is exactly the problem I get, When I var_dump the array on the included page it does not work when I do it after the include it works fine

Comment: Best would be if you put the codepart into your initial question as an addition (in the comments here it is really barely readable)

Also whereit would be interesting where affichMenuStat is called there  (at what part of the code, and what is directly before and after it ...only php wise needed). And at what line you did the output of paramStats (that is if as a command directly before affichMenuStat, ....)

Superb would also be the exact wording of the warning message.
(thus a copy of it) in your post text.

That would easen up to help you.